# How to hide the list data in web part SPD2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web-part

On my Wiki page, I added a number of web parts. I want to  display customer info which is selected. It did, it but I want to hide the other rows. Please see the img.[image]

Comment: That isn't how connected list web parts work, you want something different, you need to roll your own solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this JSLink:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      OnPostRender: function(ctx) { 
        var selectedId = GetUrlKeyValue('SelectedID')
        if (ctx.ListTitle == "LookingUpList 2") {
          var header = document.querySelector("[displayname=Select]").parentNode;
          var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
          for (var i = 0; i < ctx.ListData.Row.length; i++) {
            var listItem = ctx.ListData.Row[i];
            var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, listItem);
            var row = document.getElementById(iid);
            if(selectedId && !row.querySelector("td:nth-child(" + index + ") > img[alt=Selected]")){
              row.style.display = "none"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      ListTemplateType: 100
    });
  }
  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/SelectHideOtherRows.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

You will only have to change the URL in this line to make it MDS safe:

`RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/SelectAndHideOtherRows.js"), init);`

Comment: Thank you Daniel i have one question where can i write this code  i am new in SP please tell me.

Comment: You could, for example, upload a JS file called "SelectHideOtherRows.js" with the code in it to your root Style Library. Then edit the page that has the List View Webpart on it >> edit the List View Webpart itself >> add the path ("~siteCollection/Style Library/SelectHideOtherRows.js") to the JSLink field in the Miscellaneous section of the webpart properties pane.

Comment: Hey when i added this js and open the page it show nothing on my page show blank page.

Comment: Your webparts are gone? Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Not single error in console. Just display blank page.

Comment: Let's move to the chat for the troubleshooting: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45080/chat-with-admin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45089/discussion-between-admin-and-daniel-stolzner).

Answer (score 0):

You can create Views in the respective list.
Then edit page -> list webpart properties 
And choose the new view from the available list.

If the filter value is coming from another webpart then you can use the connected webpart feature.

Comment: Thank you for reply  i want to just hide other customer when i select the customer.

Comment: You mean you want to hide the other rows?

Comment: Yes i want to hide the other rows